# How do you force Javafx to immediately update width property?

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx

I'm having an issue where I need javafx to update a `Label`'s `widthProperty` immediately after changing the text in that `Label`. It appears after changing after changing text it takes the application an additional cycle to update  the width of that `Label`.

Specifically I have a custom color picker object, which has `Label` with the color hex value laid on top of a `Circle`, with a hidden `ColorPicker` behind both of them.

I want to update this object when the value of the color picker changes. The problem however is that when I try to rescale the `Label`, the old width property is used causing it to scale incorrectly:

```
   colorPicker.valueProperty().addListener((Observable e) ->{
        circle.setFill(colorPicker.getValue());
        colorText.setText(colorPicker.getValue().toString());
        colorText.setTextFill(colorPicker.getValue().invert());

        //The values are set before the function call, but the width isn't updated
        scaleText();
    });
```

.

```
private void scaleText(){
    colorText.applyCss(); //I was hoping this line would force an update, but no dice
    if(circle.getRadius() == 0d || colorText.getWidth() == 0d){
        return;
    }
    //The following line of code will use the old width property
    double scale = (circle.getRadius()*1.60)/colorText.getWidth();
    colorText.setScaleX(scale);
    colorText.setScaleY(scale);
}
```

I know that this is the value not being updated immediately because I was able to 'fix' the issue by running `scaleText()` after a delay from another thread:

```
new Thread(() -> {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(25);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(ColorPickerCircle.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
            scaleText();
        }).start();
```

However I would like to find a solution that doesn't rely on delaying the function call from another thread. So my question boils down to: **Is there any way to force an immediate `widthProperty` update?**

Comment: What's the `applyCss()` function doing?

Comment: Try calling `layout()` in addition to `applyCSS()` on the *parent* of the label.

Comment: @AntJavaDev Currently it doesn't appear to be doing anything, I saw that it was recommended sometimes to apply styling before initialization. But it doesn't perform any action in this code at the moment, it was just a shot in the dark at bug fixing by me.

Comment: @James_D I will give it a shot, but the parent is the custom `StackPane` object that all these functions/objects are a part of, and it is height and width properties are locked.

Comment: @James_D Thank you for the suggestion, but it unfortunately did not work.

Comment: Well, `layout()` should lay out the stack pane regardless of that. It sounds as though you are really fighting against using the API in the way it was designed here. Perhaps you need to rethink you strategy from a higher-level view.

Comment: I suggest you create a [MCVE].

Comment: @James_D Actually layout does appear to be functioning, thank you. If you make it an answer to this question I will accept it as the answer. If you have any suggestions as to how to make the question more complete I would be happy to add them into the question.

Comment: @luckydog32 tbh I don't really want to encourage others to use this kind of approach, as I don't think it's really appropriate for a site aimed at professional programmers.

Comment: @James_D What would be a better approach?

Comment: I don't know what you're trying to do, but it sounds like you are making something like a custom control. If so, you should design it like the standard controls, with a skin class that extends skin base and overrides the usual layout methods to size and position the child nodes.